# Question about simulating clock modules in Omnet++

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++

Scenario:

Node 1 (Sender) has a local clock (40.000 MHz) and sends this clock signal as a continuous bit stream (01010101...) on a serial (i.e. fiberoptic) link to Node 2 (Receiver).

Node 2 has its own (local or global, e.g. 41.000 MHz) clock and must determine the phase and frequency of the local clock of Node 1 with respect to its own clock using the (clock) data it is receiving from Node 1.

Alternatively, I can think of Node 1 sending individual messages, but at a well-defined frequency of 40.000 MHz, to Node 2. Again, Node 2 (which has its own local or global 41.000 MHz clock) must determine the phase and frequency of Node 1's local clock with respect to its own clock using the arrival timing of the messages it is receiving from Node 1

Question: How would I implement either of these scenarios in OMNet++?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know OMNet++ but if you have the *ticks* of both clocks, would

```
the_other_clocks_freq = the_other_clocks_ticks*your_own_freq/your_own_ticks
```

work to get the frequency? Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Clock {
    uint64_t m_freq;
    uint64_t m_ticks;
public:
    Clock(uint64_t Base) : m_freq(Base), m_ticks(0) {}
    void tick() { ++m_ticks; }
    operator double () const { return static_cast<double>(m_ticks)/static_cast<double>(m_freq); }
    uint64_t getTicks() const { return m_ticks; }
    uint64_t getOtherClockFreq(uint64_t other_ticks) {
        return (other_ticks*m_freq)/m_ticks;
    }

};
int main() {
    Clock Node1(40000000);
    Clock Node2(41000000);

    // simulate 0.00075s
    for(int i=0; i<40000*75/100; ++i) Node1.tick();
    for(int i=0; i<41000*75/100; ++i) Node2.tick();

    std::cout << Node1 << "s\n"; // 0.00075s
    std::cout << Node2 << "s\n"; // 0.00075s

    // calculate the base freq of the other clock
    std::cout << Node1.getOtherClockFreq(Node2.getTicks()) << " Node2 base\n";
    std::cout << Node2.getOtherClockFreq(Node1.getTicks()) << " Node1 base\n";
}
```

Output

```
0.00075s
0.00075s
41000000 Node2 base
40000000 Node1 base
```

At these speeds you may need something larger than `uint64_t` to store the ticks though ... and I don't know what phase is in this case.